# Removing duplicate from list of lists

Tags: python

I've got this simplified list of lists:

```
nlist = [['E:\\photos\\IMG 1860 - Copy.jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1860.jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1873(2).jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1873(2).jpg']]
```

What I want to achieve is to remove duplicates from it, my code does not work and I know why but I cannot figure out workaround:

```
for b in range(len(nlist[0])-1):
    if nlist[0][b] == nlist[0][b+1]:
        print(nlist[0][b]) #it prints this line but get "IndexError: list index out of range" after
        del nlist[0][b]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You're modifying the list while you're iterating over it - that's a recipe for disaster (the range will iterate over the original length, but you're making it smaller inside your loop). Instead, you can create a set - it'll only contain unique values. so `set(nlist)` and avoid the whole loop construct.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
nlist = [['E:\\photos\\IMG 1860 - Copy.jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1860.jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1873(2).jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1873(2).jpg']]

no_duplicates = [list(set(lst)) for lst in nlist]
print(no_duplicates)
```

output

```
[['E:\\photos\\IMG 1873(2).jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1860.jpg', 'E:\\photos\\IMG 1860 - Copy.jpg']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a set:

```
list(set(nlist[0]))
```

This removes only the elements with the same name, will not remove the - Copy names.